# Writing thesis in overleaf. How to create a sub-folder?

Tags: folders, overleaf

I'm using the template of University of Bristol Thesis on overleaf.com. I'd like to create a folder of **chapter02** inside the folder of **chapters**. But I can't seem to do so. I can manually add a new folder but it goes to files rather than goes inside a specific folder **chapters**.

[This](https://www.overleaf.com/help/187-how-can-i-create-nested-folders-slash-subfolders#.V1XWgTUrLIU) doesn't work for me.

Below is the code of template. I'm confused of input and import command.

I tried to add

```
\import{chapters/chapter02/} %or
\input{chapters/chapter02/}
```

But they don't work. I got error message

```
 ! LaTeX Error: File `chapters/chapter02/.tex' not found.
    l.373 \input{chapters/chapter02/}
                                     {chap02.tex}^^M
```

Example：

```
%\title{University of Bristol Thesis Template}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{frontmatter/title}
\input{frontmatter/abstract}
\input{frontmatter/dedication}
\input{frontmatter/declaration}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\tableofcontents*
\addtocontents{toc}{\par\nobreak \mbox{}\hfill{\bf Page}\par\nobreak}
\listoftables
\addtocontents{lot}{\par\nobreak\textbf{{\scshape Table} \hfill Page}\par\nobreak}
\listoffigures
\addtocontents{lof}{\par\nobreak\textbf{{\scshape Figure} \hfill Page}\par\nobreak}
\mainmatter
\import{chapters/chapter01/}{chap01.tex}
% Here neither input nor import don't work.
% \input{chapters/chapter02/}
% \import{chapters/chapter02/}
\appendix
\import{chapters/appendices/}{app0A.tex}
\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{siam}
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\bibliography{thesisbiblio}
\end{document}
```

**Update: Thanks for all the help. There is a tip to create sub folder on Overleaf. See @LianTze Lim's reply.**

Comment: "But it doesn't work for me." What exactly doesn't work? (Please post the relevant error messages if there are any. Or else describe the observed behavior so we can compare to what is expected to happen.)

Comment: With `\input`, you would be using the wrong syntax. So of course it doesn't work. Does it work if you do `\input{chapters/chapter02/chap02}`? Alternatively, what does the error message say if you use `\import`? Did you in fact verify that the relevant file actually exists? (And to be ultra-clear: does the first `\import` command for `chap01.tex` work?)

Comment: Like I wrote, the command `\input{chapters/chapter02/}{chap02.tex}` would NEVER work, since that's not the correct syntax. Please stop showing the error output for THAT command, and instead show the error output if you replace it by one of `\input{chapters/chapter02/chap02}` (exactly as I wrote here) or `\import{chapters/chapter02/}{chap02.tex}`.

Comment: I wouldn't use a template.

Comment: @WillieWong thanks. Yes you're right. The first '\import' is from the template so it works. chap02.tex doesn't exist. I'm just trying to add a folder of chapter02 under the folder chapters here. I tried '\input{chapters/chapter02/}' but got similar error ! LaTeX Error: File `chapters/chapter02/.tex' not found.'' I will edit my question now.

Comment: Ah, I think this is the relevant quote: **"chap02.tex doesn't exist. I'm just trying to add a folder of chapter02 under the folder chapters here. "** The short version is "don't do that." The slightly longer version is "you can do that _if_ you create the file chap02.tex; you can even leave it empty. But it has to be there."

Comment: Two years ago there was no official UoB template. A few unofficial templates were kicking around but I was unimpressed.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks. Hopefully I'm not asking too much, but do you mean that in order to create a new sub folder I have to create the file within the folder? I have added chap02.tex, and used the code `\import{chapters/chapter02/}{chap02.tex}`. Nothing happened. No folder was created under chapters...

Comment: @Sile_Li Now it appears you are asking about the user interface for Overleaf.com. I am not familiar with it so I cannot help necessarily. But have you tried following the instruction [here](https://www.overleaf.com/help/189-how-do-i-create-a-folder-or-subfolder-in-my-project#.V1Xo9EphnRY) to create a folder/subfolder? You don't create a folder by putting in TeX code. TeX doesn't do that. You create a folder using the Overleaf (or whatever operating system/interface) and read files from the folder using TeX.

Comment: In particular: you are supposed to create the file `chap02.tex` INSIDE the subfolder `chapters/chapter02/` which you create yourself (without the help of TeX).

Comment: Thanks @WillieWong. I have read the link of overleaf, but it didn't work either. I named my folder as chapters/chapter02 and then I just created a folder named chapters/chapter02... not a folder under chapters. I have emailed overleaf asking for help. I will update my post once I solve this problem. Thanks a lot for clarifying that it's not to do with TeX code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

%% 01 is .tex file inside the shown hierarchy
\input{Chapters/chapter01/01} 
\input{Chapters/chapter02/02}
\input{Chapters/chapter03/03

\end{document}
```

and you could do

```
\chapter{Intro}
...
```

for 01.tex and other files.

Look on the wiki [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents) for further details.

If you have another problem, post a MWE and the error message.

**Edited after MWE:**

You are doing

```
\input{chapters/chapter02/}{chap02.tex}
```

This is not right syntax. Use

```
\input{chapters/chapter02/chap02.tex}
```

instead.

You error clearly states that ".tex" file is not found whereas you want to input "chap02.tex".

Comment: Thanks Amit. I'm now looking at the compiled file. chapter01 was added by \import. I try to add chapter02 by either \import or \input, but both don't work. Any ideas?

Comment: add your minimal code here, I and/or others can look and try to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks Amit. I tried \input{chapters/chapter02/chap02.tex}, but still got same error: ! LaTeX Error: File `chapters/chapter02/chap02.tex' not found.
l.373 \input{chapters/chapter02/chap02.tex}                                          ^^M. I'm thinking is there anything special about this template, since in the template, there is only \import{chapters/chapter01/}{chap01.tex}, I didn't see \input was used anywhere. I'm a beginner apologize if the question is too obvious. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend you to use a very minimal example ... such as `\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\input{chapters/chapter02/chap02}


\end{document}`. Check if chap02.tex exists and then see if this works ?

Comment: Thanks Amit. I created a new project with the following code `\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
content
\input{chapters/chapter01/}
\end{document}`. Yet still got same error `! LaTeX Error: File chapters/chapter01/.tex not found.` Any ideas? Thanks a mill.

Comment: @Sile_Li, please pay careful attention to what I and others are suggesting. If you write only `\input{chapters/chapter01/}`, this means, compiler will look for the ".tex" file inside the directory "chapters/chapter01". Since you have not providing anything after "/", it simply try to look for ".tex" file. Your file name is "chap01.tex", so please write file name after the folder location. `\input{chapters/chapter01/chap01} `.

Comment: Thanks Amit for your help. I'd like to reiterate my question maybe it's not clear. How to create a folder chapter02 under the folder chapters? I can manually add a folder but it goes under files, rather than under specific folder chapters. I think I don't have to create "chap.tex" for that? Thx!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40795/discussion-between-sile-li-and-amit).

Comment: Hi @Sile_Li, there's a trick to creating subfolders on Overleaf, explained here: https://www.overleaf.com/help/187-how-can-i-create-nested-folders-slash-subfolders and here: https://www.overleaf.com/help/189-how-do-i-create-a-folder-or-subfolder-in-my-project (it's a limitation of the current filetree that we're working to fix). If you're continuing to have trouble, please send us a message at https://www.overleaf.com/contact and we'll help there. Thanks, John

Comment: Thanks @JohnHammersley. I read the link and named my folder as chapters/chapter02 but then I just created a folder named chapters/chapter02... not a folder under chapters. I have emailed overleaf asking for help. Will update this post once I figure it out. Thx!

Comment: @Sile_Li When you create the empty folder `chapters/chapter02` on Overleaf, it shows up as a "flat" folder directly under the main folder. But if you add a file to this new folder, the file hierarchy would then fall into place correctly.

Alternatively, you can also add a blank file in the `chapters` folder, but give it the name `chapter02/chap02.tex`. That would also immediately make the file hierarchy fall into place.

Here's an animated GIF to help make things clearer: https://www.dropbox.com/s/twgkg06f3ayoinz/sileli-subfolders.gif?dl=0

Comment: Perfect. Thank you LianTze for the comments and your reply by email.